# Fastest way to update a DataGridView connected to asynchronously and constantly updating DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm currently using a DataGridView and a DataTable as so:

`mydataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;`

`myDataTable` is constantly receiving new information from a webfeed. The issue I'm having is that `myDataGridView` will remain stagnant when `myDataTable` has changed. I'm guessing this has to do with being on a UI thread, and `myDataTable` being updated asynchronously. `myDataGridView` will draw the current `myDataTable` upon being unminimized.

This, of course, is not user friendly by any standards. I would think to asynchronously loop `myDataGridView.Refresh()` but this is not a solution as the form is going to spend all of it's time redrawing the DGV extremely slowly, and I need it to update with real time data constantly. Am I trying to fit a square peg into a round hole by using DataTable -> DGV for real time data?

Comment: Virtual Mode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-jit-data-loading-in-the-datagrid, and you might need to skip the DataTable overhead if possible

Comment: There are many options depending on the DB which we can only guess at.  `myDataGridView.Refresh()` does nothing of course because repainting the *control* is not the same as refreshing the data. How do you know that new data in the DB Table is getting fed into the DT but *not* showing in the DGV?  Refreshing the DataTable is pretty trivial and well documented

Comment: @Plutonix `myDataTable` is receiving information from a `webfeed` (should've clarified in OP, will correct). The only semblance of a DB running in the application is the `DataTable` itself. In `myDataGridView`, if I click on sells after `myDataTable` has been populated, the cell I clicked on shows the information correctly. Then I start clicking around the DGV and the cells start showing up.